# Running Windows 7 through external USB hard drive on Windows 8 machine

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, laptop, usb, external-hard-drive

We have just relocated from the US from the UK. 
In the UK my husband was using an HP computer with a 1TB Western Digital Hard Drive which says it is SATA with 64MB Cache and has the code WD10EARS on it. It had Windows 7 64 bit.

We were advised by a techie friend that instead of taking the entire computer out (not an option for us) we could take the hard drive and then use another computer or laptop to access the Windows 7 OS.

We purchased a hard drive enclosure (with cooling fan) which is the NexStar - HX with 3.0 USB and eSATA. I have accessed the files etc from the hard drive using this enclosure (using both eSATA and the USB cables) on both this laptop and my old Toshiba Satelite. (NB I tried to boot on my Toshiba through the eSATA, I just got a flash of blue screen and then in defaulted back to my own desktop).

That's fine but my husband needs to access the OS desktop and the applications on there to continue his work. I have read about boot sequence and have attempted to chance to boot order to make the USB device (this laptop (HP Pavilion Win 8.1) we are using is my father-in-laws and does not have eSATA) but my attempt didn't work. I have selected the option 'USB diskette on key/USB Hard disk' and moved it to the top of the sequence. The hard drive was connected and on. I rebooted and still the orginal laptop operating system was booted.

The current specs for this laptop are:
 Processor: AMD A6-5200 APU with Radeon (TM) HD Graphics 2.00 GHz
RAM: 6.00 GB

I've gone as far as my slight IT knowledge will allow. As this laptop isn't ours I'm scared to do too much playing around in BIOS.

Using this laptop is a trial really as we'd like to purchse our own that my husband can use to record his music one etc - either through Windows 7 or to move everything from the old hard drive to the laptop. We want to be sure he can access the win7 desktop to do his work while we get our own.

If we get our own, are we best to get one without a HDD at all and just run this, or get a Linux system and run this alongside? I've read about partitioning but don't really know anything about it - do we need to do that?

I hope that makes sense and I appreciate any help you can give us to get the Win 7 working (plus purchase of a laptop for home music recording).

Thanks

Comment: shut the system down, and plug the usb drive in. then power it on. when you see the Toshiba logo flash up on the screen, hit F12. you may need to hit it a few times. this should bring up a menu which asks you what device to boot from. hopefully your usbdisk will be displayed there, and you can select it to boot. Unfourtunately, there is a good likelyhood that the win7 OS will not work with the laptop. or it might. it depends on what is different between the old hardware and the laptop, and the degree of differance. good luck.

Comment: I don't know if you noticed my note but when I selected the eSATA to boot from I got a flash of blue screen and then it just went to my ordinary desktop.

With the HP it doesn't seem to load at all. Is it because it's a PC hard drive?

Comment: that unfortunately means that the installed os does not have critical components installed to support your hardware. are you able to boot into Safe mode or Recovery console? http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/start-computer-safe-mode#start-computer-safe-mode=windows-7  recovery console's Startup Repair may work, but be sure to back up your user data to another location in case the old OS is damaged beyond repair. http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-get-to-the-recovery-console-in-windows.html

Comment: By critical components do you mean it's not powerful enough? It's only a small laptop. I don't want to delve too deep and risk damaging the HP or Toshiba.

We want to get a laptop specifically to run this HDD for my husbnds recording. Are we best getting a computer with no HDD, or at least one that doesn't have an OS installed and plugging this in through eSATA? Or should we get a Linux devise? Or I've heard for partitioning but don't really know much about it. This whole thing is less about getting this HDD to work on the devices we DO have and more about getting one it will work on.

Comment: Sorry for all the questions, we're a bit out of our depth after 'advice' that plugging it in will be fine.

Comment: Well, what I mean is, the windows installation adapts itself to the hardware its installed on, so I don't mean anything about the systems "power". the devices are just different, and need to be used in different ways. that's what a driver is; a piece of code that knows how to use a specific device. so the windows installation on your external hard disk isn't able to run on the differant hardware. sometimes windows can boot without all the drivers it needs, or with the wrong drivers, and then repair itself, but in your case, the compatibility is too serious.

Comment: Part of the issue is that this is a laptop. you will probably have better luck with a desktop, since the basic drivers are less finicky than with a laptop. Your friend has probably been able to do this a few times, but the situation varies from computer to computer. Its only been for the last couple versions of windows that you had any hope of running a windows OS on hardware that isn't almost identical to what it was originally installed on. Do you have a win7 CD, and perhaps know the license key for the win7 installation?

Comment: First, I recommend getting a new computer with a HDD. you can add the USB disk to it internally, or keep using it over USB. I do recommend you use a windows OS, so if you already have a windows disk and key, use it instead of buying a new one. install windows on the HDD that comes with the new PC, rather than trying to partition and install windows on the USB drive. use that drive for your user files instead, since its a large disk. Good luck.

Comment: I get ya. We can access all of the files we need and some software can be reinstalled. My husband's main upset was all the rating he had done on the itunes on the HDD and he didn't export the playlist before we left. We don't have the CD and key here with us unfortunately. I tried to open the itunes that is on the HDD but I got an error message...if I could access that then my husband would certainly be happier. Then we could just get a new system and transfer across all we need.

Comment: you should be able to restore the iTunes DB to the new PC. http://www.ilounge.com/index.php/articles/comments/recovering-an-itunes-library-onto-a-new-pc/